# Classes and this with a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have series of inputfields that i have given the class **replaceInput**. The point with this is to have a simple function that replace the value to empty when the user focus in the field and take it back to X if the field is empty on focus out.

My question is, is this a syntax-error or is it possible that when i moved the logic to a separat function **this** does not work with the class? If i just use the class, every value is empty every time.

**HTML**

```
<input id="goal" class="biggerFont replaceInput"  value="X" >
```

**jQuery and javascript**

```
$( ".replaceInput" ).focusin(function() {
        placeholderFix('X', '');

            //OLD  WORKING CODE
              /*if ($(this).val() == 'X') {
                $(this).val('');
              };*/
          });



function placeholderFix(oldValue, newValue){
  $(this).val() == oldValue ? $(this).val(newValue): $(this).val(oldValue);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass that object to the new function. In `placeholderFix` method, `this` is not refering to the input element.

```
$( ".replaceInput" ).focusin(function() {
        placeholderFix('X', '',this);

            //OLD  WORKING CODE
              /*if ($(this).val() == 'X') {
                $(this).val('');
              };*/
          });



function placeholderFix(oldValue, newValue,obj){
  $(obj).val() == oldValue ? $(obj).val(newValue): $(obj).val(oldValue);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**`bind()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

> The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

*Code*

```
$(".replaceInput").focusin(function () {
    placeholderFix.bind(this)('X', '');
});

function placeholderFix(oldValue, newValue) {
    $(this).val() == oldValue ? $(this).val(newValue) : $(this).val(oldValue);
}
```

[**Simplified DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3Br2R/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to call your function with a custom `this` argument:

```
$( ".replaceInput" ).focusin(function() {
    placeholderFix.call(this, 'X', '');
});

function placeholderFix(oldValue, newValue){
    $(this).val() == oldValue ? $(this).val(newValue): $(this).val(oldValue);
}
```

Comment: Even `call` is another way of doing it. Simple demo of call http://jsfiddle.net/nrej4/

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line of code

```
placeholderFix('X', '');
```

to

```
placeholderFix('X', '' , this);
```

so that `this` refers to input element.